# Comparing generic types in Java, how to ignore the caps if the type is a String?

Tags: java, comparison, case-insensitive

I have a problem when comparing generic type, I have a Entry and now I have to compare the key with another key, so without thinking I made the equals ...

```
private DListNode<Entry<K,V>> findNode(K key){
        DListNode<Entry<K, V>> node = head;

        while(node != null && !node.getElement().getKey().equals(key))
            node = node.getNext();

        return node;
    }
```

**!node.getElement().getKey().equals(key)**

But the problem, obviously, is that if I have a string and the caps case exclusion will not happen.... equalsIgnoreCase can't be used of course.

So how can I make this to works with every type? Including the strings with caps

Comment: What stops you from checking if result of `getKey()` is `instanceof String`?

Comment: it's a generic type, I'm comparing a K . Can be a string, but may not be too.

Comment: Nothing stop me, but if I do that I have to make a cast after, so every time I want to compare to keys I will have to check is they are instance of String e make casts.... Java doesn't have nothing to solve this cases?

Comment: Hah!  I started writing my answer before the three comments above were posted.  But there really is no other option than using `instanceof` in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private DListNode<Entry<K,V>> findNode(K key){
    DListNode<Entry<K, V>> node = head;

    while(node != null && !specialEquals(node.getElement().getKey(),key))
        node = node.getNext();

    return node;
}

private static boolean specialEquals(K key1, K key2) {
    if( key1 instanceof String && key2 instanceof String ) {
        return ((String) key1).equalsIgnoreCase((String) key2);
    } else {
        return key1.equals(key2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I thought in compareTo? If I compare two Strings with compare to it will exclude the case sensitive?

Comment: No.  `String` has `compareTo` and `compareToIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a real requirement then there are two logical solutions that come to mind....

first option is to just convert all the key values in the map to lowercase (or uppercase) when you insert them, and then you won't have to worry about case in the compare.

The other option is to use a special wrapper for each Key that does the equals method for you:

```
class CaseInsensitiveString {
    private final String mystring;

    public CaseInsensitiveString(String val) {
        mystring = val;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof CaseSensitiveString
               && mystring.equalsIgnoreCase(((CaseInsensitiveString)o).getString())
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return mystring.tolowercase().hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return mystring;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way, use `instanceof` keyword

```
while (node != null && node.getKey() != null) {

    if (key instanceof String) {
        String sKey = (String)key;
        if (node.getKey() instanceof String) {
            String nodeKeyString = (String)node.getKey();
            if (nodeKeyString.equalsIgnoreCase(sKey)) {
                return node;
            }
        }
    } else if (node.getKey().equals(key)) {
        return node;
    } else {
        node = node.getNext();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if your key are `Comparable`, you can customize your `Comparable` to deal with case-insensitive `String` key value.

I hope this helps.